# Python Pandas Matplotlib : How to Plot Graph without Numerics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot bar graph or graphs in python using a Pandas dataframe using two columns that don't contain numeric. One column is Operating System, another is computer name, I want to plot a graph between them showing which OS is running over how many Systems, the sample data is like below.

[image: Sample Data, Two of the many rows]

How can I plot bar graph or other graphs for these two colums. When I try the code below:

```
ax = dfdefault[['Operating System','Computer Name']].plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xlabel("Hour", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("V", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

I get this error:

```
Error: 
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you are trying to plot. Do you want a histogram-like plot for `Operating System`?

Comment: yes histogram will serve the purpose, even pie charts will do, i want something simple that could give a general idea, histogram is ok

Answer (score 1):

You will need to count the occurrence of each operating system first and then plot using a bar graph or pie chart. `bar` expects numeric data already, which you don't have. Counting will take care of this. Here is an example using a pie chart:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['asd', 'win'],
     ['sdf', 'mac'],
     ['aww', 'win'],
     ['dd',  'linux']],
    columns=['computer', 'os']
)
df['os'].value_counts().plot.pie()
```

[image]

A bar chart would work similarly. Just change `pie` to `bar`.

Comment: I have many , around 50 columns in pandas represented by df['OS', 'Computer','c1','c2',.........'c50'] .  I want to plot a pie or any thing in two columns- [OS, Computer]. Sorry to ask silly things , but I am not able to figure out how. @busybear

Comment: Are the other columns relevant? In fact, `Computer` doesn't seem relevant in this case. You just need to count how many times an operating system appears in your dataframe correct? That's why I count values in `df['os']` in the post.

Comment: Not relevent for this case, quite the thing I want to do, Thanq, let me try this.

Comment: Just one more thing, any way possible to club two OS - like Windows 10, Windows 10 Home, , Windows server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, I want to club one or more to make it one. If this is possible.

Comment: You are going to have to check if each element is contained in a list/set of values that you deem the "same". You can also create a dictionary to do this. If you aren't sure how to do that, you can edit your post. However, you should really ask in a new post if you can't find your answer with a search.